# Provide a single Excel Formula for calculating Binomial Coefficients (N,K) in Excel with positive or negative N

Tags: excel, binomial-coefficients

Is there a single excel formula that can take integer inputs N and K and generate the binomial coefficient (N,K), for positive or negative (or zero) values of N?

The range of N and K should be fairly small e.g. -11 < N < +11 and -1 < K < +11.  Otherwise large numbers will be generated that exceed excel's capabilities.

---

**CONTEXT**

Excel does not provide a Binomial function.  So how how to get around this?  The binomial function for positive N is straightforward:- Binomial(N,K) = Factorial(N)/(Factorial(N-K)*Factorial(K)).  But this doesn't work for *negative* N.

For information on Binomial Coefficients there is useful stuff in Ken Ward's pages on [Pascals Triangle](https://trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/pascalsTriangle.htm#Table%20Pascals%20Triangle) and [Extended Pascal's Triangle](https://trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/pascalsExtendedTriangle.htm#Pascals_Extended_Triangle_for_Negative_n).

I wanted to make a similar tabular resource in Excel...but with one single table covering positive, zero and negative values of $N$.

One efficient way of doing this is to define a single formula which can be used in every cell of the table.  The formula should discriminate between values of N which are negative, zero, or positive and use appropriate logic to obtain the correct output in each case.

Of course, rather than build a whole table, the same formula can be used to calculate the binomial coefficient for a single (N,K) input pair of values.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs The note you deleted was inserted by me because previously I was getting flak for answering my own question despite Stack Exchange welcoming such Q&A style questions. I would like to keep it there.

Comment: I thought that was the case, though its a fact that people complaining about that were in the wrong, its a basic Stack Exchange / StackOverflow policy (and always has been - https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer ) that self-answered questions are welcome and encouraged. Because of that I thought (especially since some time had passed) that the notes detracted from the actual question.

Comment: That said, if you still prefer to have the text in there, by all means - I can undo my edit or feel free to do so yourself, I wasn't trying to impose anything unwanted. And / or leaving these comments or some other comment is another way of addressing it.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs Thanks. I agree with your suggestion to leave these comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simulate a binomial function by using a conditional formula in a single Excel cell which takes as input the contents of two other cells.

e.g. if worksheet cells A1 and A2 contain the numeric values corresponding to N,K in the binomial expression (N,K) then the following conditional formula can be put in another worksheet cell (e.g. A3)...

```
=IF(A1>-1,IF(B1>A1,0,(FACT(A1)/(FACT(B1)*FACT(A1-B1)))),(-1)^(B1)*(FACT(-A1-1+B1)/(FACT(B1)*FACT(-A1-1+B1-B1))))
```

This will handle positive and negative (and zero) values of N.  In this solution both N and K must be integers (including zero).  There is a limit to the size of N and K that excel will be able to cope with (but I havent tested the limits beyond the range -11

The excelf formula uses the conditional construct: IF(test,operation if true, operation if false).

In pseudo-code the logic is as follows:-

```
IF(N>-1) THEN
    IF(K>N) THEN
        Result = 0
    ELSE
        Result = (N!)/(K!*(N-K)!)
    ENDIF
ELSE
    Result = (-1)^(K) * (-N-1+K)! / ( (K)! * (-N-1+K-K)! )
ENDIF
```

Note the formula uses the [Upper Negation Identity](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Negated_Upper_Index_of_Binomial_Coefficient) to determine coefficients when N is negative:-

(-N,K) = (-1)^K * (K-N-1,K).

---

**Pascal's Triangle Table**

To create a "Pascal's Triangle"-type table for negative and positive values of N, proceed as follows.

(1) Create a new blank excel worksheet.

(2) In column B put the integer N values (starting at cell B4 and proceeding downwards):-

```
e.g Nmin,Nmin-1,...-2,-1,0,1,2,3,...,Nmax-1,Nmax.
```

(3) In row 3 put the integer K values (starting at cell C3 and proceeding rightwards):-

```
0,1,2,3,...Kmax.
```

(4) Then in cell (C4) enter the conditional formula:-

```
=IF($B4>-1,IF(C$3>$B4,0,(FACT($B4)/(FACT(C$3)*FACT($B4-C$3)))),(-1)^(C$3)*(FACT(-$B4-1+C$3)/(FACT(C$3)*FACT(-$B4-1+C$3-C$3))))
```

(5) Copy cell C4 and paste it to all cells in the grid bounded (at left and at top) by your N and K values.

The grid cells will then contain the binomial ceofficient corresponding to (N,K).

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who ends up here through google, Excel actually does have COMBIN for N >= K >= 0. If you know the inputs would otherwise be valid, one option for handling K > N would be `IFERROR(COMBIN(N, K), 0)`, with the advantage that you only specify N and K once, and the disadvantage of hiding when your assumptions inevitably turn out to be wrong.

To bring it around to an actual answer (though honestly I'd have preferred just leaving a comment if the site would let me), the other answer's formula can then be simplified to

```
IF(A1>-1,IF(B1>A1,0,COMBIN(A1,B1)),(-1)^(B1)*COMBIN(-A1-1+B1,B1))
```

as a bonus, it seems to be able to handle a larger range of inputs, as however COMBIN is implemented avoids the issue of the FACTs temporarily exceeding 1.8e308 even though much of that would be cancelled out in the division.